# how to set up an svn thing in a live server so that i won't have to use an ftp client anymore ?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a typical hosting account with control panel, ssh access, now my question is, how to set up svn or git on that live account? so that whenever i develop something, I won't have to use FTP client, just commit using svn or push using git ?

Comment: You need to clarify what you're trying to accomplish -- this question as you've written it makes little to no sense...

Answer (score 2):

Assumption, since you mentioned using git/svn: You're using this server to store your codebase.

Since you have SSH access, the easiest thing to do is set up git-over-ssh to do your push.

I hate saying 'lmgtfy', but any number of google searches for 'git over ssh' will give you a tutorial on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've mistaken what SVN/Git are intended to be used for.

It sounds to me that you want to deploy your "developed thing" to a production [serving] environment. SVN/Git/et. al. are repositories for managing change within something (a program's source code, a web site's various files, etc.) So one "checks in" or "commits" to these repositories.

What one does with the "stuff" being managed in the repo is totally up to you. You can use "post commit" scripts in various forms to do things. You can construct automated check-out-and-build scripts, etc. But I don't see how you could auto-deploy-to-production-environment when you check something in. At the very least, you'd want to only go-to-production when you tag the repo for a release...

Bigger picture: If you're in a managed hosting environment, I don't think you'd have the level of access you'd need to get in and bend these tools to do what you think you want to do.

Answer (score -2):

you could install [uberSVN](http://www.ubersvn.com/) on the server so you have a nice web interface to the manage the subversion server